# Setting Background of Viewport3DX to Transparent

Tags: direct2d, helix-3d-toolkit

I am using the Viewport3DX from Helix Toolkit only to Draw into the Content2D Element.
This works fine and very fast.

But the background is White and I would like to have an transparent background.
I can set BackgroundColor to another color but not to Transparent.
ALso the Background Property has no effect.

Is this normal issue is there an hidden option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So now I know more.
With EnableSwapChainRendering = true the viewport uses HWND to render in the WPF control and therefore there's no transparency.
With EnableSwapChainRendering = false it renders to an D3DImage and transparency works.